# Replacing all duplicate numbers in an Array, so that every element is unique in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops, random, duplicates

The elements in the array are created using rand().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int array[6] = { 0 };
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        array[i] = rand() % 49 + 1;
    }
    
    /*
        Code to check for duplicates
        if duplicate found
            duplicate = rand(49);
    */
    
    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++){
            printf("[%d]",array[i]);
        }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I don´t really want to sort the array if it makes it easier to find duplicates because the array is for a lottery ticket.
I have tried different methods, but all of them are inefficient and includes a lot of loops.
I had different approaches, but all of them didn´t really work, because what if, the newly created number, is yet again a duplicate? Or if the last number in the array is a duplicate.
So I came with the following approach: The algorithm will create as many areas, as long no number in the array is a duplicate

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1

int main(void) {
    int a[6] = {0};
    srand(time(NULL));

    while (TRUE) {

        int c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            a[i] = rand() % 49 + 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 6; j++) {
                if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (c == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any Ideas, how to make an easy, efficient, but not so complex algorithm for a beginner?

Thanks :)

Comment: The usual way to do what you want is to get an array with all the numbers (`int arr[49] = { 1, 2, 3, ..., 48, 49};`) then shuffle it (with [Fischer-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)) and show the first 6 elements.

Comment: That´s an interesting idea. I´ll try it out.
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you show us your "inefficient" methods? What makes you think they are inefficient? Your array is very small so even a very naive code would be fast enough on any platform.

Comment: I packed it in the main post

Answer (score 0):

There's two sort of problems here. Firstly, if you find a duplicate number, you wish it to be replaced by another number. However, it is also possible that the new number could be a duplicate to some other value. I'd suggest adding the following code to your program to check for duplicacy

```
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
   for(int k=0; k<6; k++)
   {
      if(i==k)
      {
         continue;
      }
      if(array[i] == array[k])
      {
         array[i]=rand()%49+1;
      }
   }
}
```

There is an outer loop to rotate between the 6 elements of the array, and an inner loop to test that element against all other elements of that array. However, you should note that it is entirely possible that the elements 1-5 may end up being duplicated to some other value again.

Edit: The continue; statement iterates the loop for the next value. Its there to make sure no element is tested against itself.

Comment: What if the last ```rand``` is equal to a previous one?

Comment: That's what I said. It doesn't check if the rand ends up being equal to the previous number. However, I'm looping it 6 times in the inner loop so it checks against all other elements. It'll only check if the current value is a duplicate and then replace it. It cannot check if the new value is a duplicate, because you see, the array could always potentially change.and you would have to start from all over again.

Comment: when i == k == 0 what is the value of `array[i]`

Comment: The 0th index of an array represents the first value of the said array. I'm checking if i==k so that we do not end up checking an element against itself (a number is its own duplicate)

Comment: So you are saying that your code does not work, which is true, it does not guarantee a duplicate free array. Why did you post it at all?